# Remove section number of table in Table

Tags: tables

When I recompile my document in Overleaf, it shows the citation as Table 3.0 Table 1 and the spacing between Table 1 and Sociodemographics is missing the extra hard return.  Same thing is happening with my Figures, it shows Figure 3.0 Figure 1

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption*{\textbf{Figure 1} \\ \vspace{0.5\baselineskip} \emph{Demographics (Age)}}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\textbf{Figure 1} -- Demographics by age}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Figures/age.png}
\end{figure}
```

I have redid this too many times and pulling my hair out.  Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In order for us to help, we need more information, in particular the document class and relevant packages.  Please expand your code to a compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` ad ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem. Then someone will be able to experiment and determine how to fix it.